# how to translate cyberbullying into Chinese?

Tags: translation

> cyberbully is someone who uses the internet to harm or frighten another person, especially by sending them unpleasant messages

How to translate cyberbullying into Chinese?

Comment: 网络暴力 is more commonly seen in mainland; I think in Taiwan 网路欺凌 is a popular term.

Comment: From Wikipedia (http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%BD%91%E4%B8%8A%E6%AC%BA%E5%87%8C): 網上欺凌（英语：Cyberbullying），又稱網上霸凌、網路霸凌、網絡欺凌、網絡暴力等

Comment: Term "網上欺凌" is popular in Hong Kong. It means cyberbullying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

在网上发表具有攻击性、煽动性和侮辱性的言论，造成当事人名誉损害，人们习惯称之为“网络暴力”。
In the online publication of aggressive, provocative and insulting remarks, honorary damage caused by parties, people used to call it "the network of violence".it,s from www.baidu.com

Comment: http://baike.baidu.com/subview/979872/11223738.htm

Answer (score 2):

I think is 网络暴力 or 网络霸凌

Bully = 暴力/霸凌

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Stan - I thought this person is offering 网络暴力 or 网络霸凌 as a possible answer? I can't see the comment here?

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 Oh it seems you're right, user58955 didn't put his comment as an answer. I had thought Zeon just wanted to add "霸凌" to user58955's answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Mandarin, it is translated as 网络暴力 (mainly used mainland China).
In Traditional Chinese, it is translated as 網路霸凌/網絡暴力 (used in HongKong, Taiwan)

Answer (score 2):

in my opinion, you  should use "网络暴力" to express you ideal. "网络暴力" has some symptom as following:
1).For unconfirmed or proven network events, netizens express some aggressive,provocative,insulting and untrue statements, which make parties' reputation damage ;
2).Public the privacy in real life of the parties. Therefore infringing the right of privacy
3).Harass parties, their relatives and friends in  action or  comments, which cause damage to their personal rights,.

Answer (score 1):

According to this meaning, I suggest you using "网霸、骚客"。

PS：in my mind, "黑客" means hacker, "网霸" is a kind of person that troubles others by threatening, "骚客" is invented by me according to "especially by sending them unpleasant messages"

Comment: [骚客](http://baike.baidu.com/view/575202.htm) has already had another meaning, ***poet***, ***literati***.

Comment: OP is referring to the act of bullying, not the bully.

Comment: 骚客 doesn't indicate the location, 网骚 seems better, in fact, can't think of any others which would be better than 网骚

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a word to describe the full meaning of this. I will use “没有道德的黑客” to describe the person. "网络恐吓” to describe this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

網路霸凌

the definition is the use of communication technologies for the intention of harming another person,like hacker

Answer (score 1):

wouldn't 网霸 be the perfect word for a cyberbully?

[I'm just making this up myself]

edit: oh haha it *is* the word for a cyberbully...I just checked from baidu:
`网霸(cyber bully)是指专门利用网络、手机等电子设备在虚拟空间里对别人进行攻击的现象或发动此类攻击的人。`